# Cloning the value of a number input into a div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to copy the value of an input type number

```
<input type="nubmer" id="input" value="2" min="2">
    <div id="test">
    </div>
```

and here my Javascript code

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");
var Clone=myInput.cloneNode(true);
myDiv.appendChild(Clone);
```

But it give that cloneNode() isn't a function
How can I fix this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to copy the value of an input type number

The value is a **string**, so `cloneNode` wouldn't apply.

You can either set `innerHTML` to entirely replace the contents of the div:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");
myDiv.innerHTML = myInput; // **Replaces**
```

...or use `appendChild` with `createTextNode` to *append* it to the div:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");
myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myInput)); // **Appends**
```

Answer (score 0):

`var cloneNode(true)` duplicates all the attributes and its value to another object.

You are trying to cloning the value of the above element. That's not possible. `cloneNode()` method only works for DOM elements

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
```

Instead, clone the DOM element and append it to div.

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("input");
```

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("input");
var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");
var Clone = myInput.cloneNode(true);
myDiv.appendChild(Clone);
```

```html
<input type="nubmer" id="input" value="2" min="2">
<div id="test">
```

Hope it helps!